# Picking shapes in Java 3D

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, java-3d

I need to add drag-drop feature to some shapes (say cylinders) that I have created in my Java3D application. I think I know the basic steps (though vaguely):

1. Construct a *PickCanvas* using the current *Canvas* and the root *BranchGroup*.
2. Set mode of *PickCanvas* to PickCanvas.GEOMETRY, which according to the documentation is more accurate [ **Doubt**: What is the difference between the various picking modes, i.e. BOUNDS, GEOMETRY, GEOMETRY_INTERSECT_INFO ? It is not clear to me from the documetation. What does picking by geometry really mean? ]
3. Set capabilities of objects that I want to pick. [ **Doubt**: What is the difference between these two methods of setting capabilities? -  `node.setCapability(Node.ENABLE_PICK_REPORTING)` and `PickTool.setCapabilities(node, PickTool.INTERSECT_FULL)` ? ]
4. Add a *mouseListener* to the canvas.
5. In the *mousePressed* method, I need to identify what object has been clicked, and then take appropriate action.[ **Doubt**: This is the part I am most confused about. It would be very helpful if a detailed answer could be given on how I can I identify what object has been clicked.]

Also, *what exactly are PickShapes and how will they affect the picking algorithm ?*

I am really sorry if I am asking very basic questions, but I've spent the whole day reading the docs and being a beginner, those just aren't enough for me. I'm hard pressed for time and I hope the Stackoverflow community would be generous enough to explain me my doubts with patience. Thanks a lot !

UPDATE: Just to clarify, by drag-and-drop feature, I mean that I want to translate a cylinder from one position on the canvas to some other using the usual left-mouse-press, drag and mouse-release gesture.

Answer (score 0):

To translate (and rotate) shapes, use the [MouseBehavior](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/com/sun/j3d/utils/behaviors/mouse/MouseBehavior.html) classes.  For example, with the following, rotate with left mouse button and translate with right.

```
public Test()
{
    SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
    BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

    TransformGroup rootTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    group.addChild(rootTransformGroup);
    rootTransformGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    rootTransformGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);

    ColorCube colorCube = new ColorCube(.3);
    rootTransformGroup.addChild(colorCube);

    BoundingSphere boundingSphere = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0, 0, 0), 1000);

    MouseRotate mouseRotate = new MouseRotate();
    mouseRotate.setTransformGroup(rootTransformGroup);
    mouseRotate.setSchedulingBounds(boundingSphere);
    group.addChild(mouseRotate);

    MouseTranslate mouseTrans = new MouseTranslate();
    mouseTrans.setTransformGroup(rootTransformGroup);
    mouseTrans.setSchedulingBounds(boundingSphere);
    group.addChild(mouseTrans);

    universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
    universe.addBranchGraph(group);
}
```